# Additional Moderators Needed

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, **I need to appoint another provisional Moderators to help moderate this site. Ideally, I'd appoint two, but if I only get enough suitable volunteers for a single slot... one it is!**

Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selection. You can read more about the process here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

## The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

## Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active in the site's activities;
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities;
- Leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write;
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> ```
> <h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>
>
> <h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>
>
> Notes:
>
> <why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>
>
> ---
> ```
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> ```
> I accept/decline this nomination
>
> I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am 
> generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may 
> want to know about me are…
>
> etc.
> ```

Answer (score 13):

[image]

[image]

Notes:

I enthusiastically nominate [SGP](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/42). He is well known in the Monero community. His contributions have included, making Monero presentations, organizing meetups, workgroups and drafting a well cited [response paper](https://getmonero.org/2017/04/19/an-unofficial-response-to-an-empirical-analysis-of-linkability.html) to published Monero research.

He is also very active on Stack Exchange, producing timely, valuable and popular content. His moderation experience includes but is not limited to r/MoneroMining/ r/MoneroCommunity/, r/MoneroSupport/and r/CryptoCurrency/

Comment: I accept this nomination.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[image]

Notes:

I enthusiastically nominate [dEBRUYNE](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/44), one of the most well known, active and helpful members of the Monero community. Anyone active in any of the popular Monero channels (such as Reddit, IRC, GitHub or StackExchange) has witnessed the tremendous value that he brings to the Monero ecosystem.

He is extremely active on Stack Exchange, producing timely, valuable and popular content. In fact he ranks #3 on Monero Stack Exchange for questions answered and has consistently been one of the most active users of SE moderator tools (such as voting to close questions as duplicates, when appropriate). His moderation experience outside of Stack Exchange includes but is not limited to r/Monero/, r/MoneroCommunity/ and r/Aeon/

---

I accept this nomination.

Comment: I reached out via email to @dEBRUYNE a couple of weeks back, but never heard back from them... :\ Spam, maybe?

Comment: @Jnat - I only occasionally check the email address attached to this account. Thus, I either saw your email and forgot my respond (apologies if so) or did not see your email yet. Do you want me to reply to the email for confirmation?

Comment: That'd be appreciated, yeah, @dEBRUYNE ;)

Comment: @JNat - Done. /charspam